# AWS Rename permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

In AWS I have the following

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketvideo",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfVideoBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to be able to rename objects as well but with these permissions a rename fails anyone know what I am missing ?

Answer (score 12):

in order to rename you need to add the following to your allow actions.

`"s3:GetObjectVersion",
 "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
 "s3:PutObjectAcl",
 "s3:GetObjectAcl"`

Comment: Thanks! I was missing "s3:PutObjectAcl" in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Same answer I provided here [How do you allow granting public read access to objects uploaded to AWS S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348163/how-do-you-allow-granting-public-read-access-to-objects-uploaded-to-aws-s3/63348954#63348954)

I found that certain actions (like renaming an object) will fail when executed from the console (but will succeed from the CLI!) when **ListAllMyBuckets** is not granted for **all** s3 resources. Adding the following to the IAM policy resolved the issue:

```
 {
      "Sid": "AccessS3Console",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
```

Some of the actions I tested that failed from the console but succeeded from CLI:

- Renaming an object. The console displays "Error - Failed to rename the file to ". **Workaround**: deleting and re-uploading the object with a new name.
- Uploading an object with "Grant public read access to this object(s)". The console's status bar shows that the operation is stuck in "in progress". **Workaround**: Uploading the object without granting public read access, and then right clicking on it and selecting "Make public".

I experienced these issues after following the instructions here
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/ which describe how to restrict access to a single bucket (and preventing seeing the full list of buckets in the account). The post didn't mention the caveats.

> To limit a user's Amazon S3 console access to only a certain bucket or
> folder (prefix), change the following in the user's AWS Identity and
> Access Management (IAM) permissions:
>
> 1. Remove permission to the s3:ListAllMyBuckets action.
> 2. Add permission to s3:ListBucket only for the bucket or folder that you want the user to access.
>    Note: To allow the user to upload and download objects from the bucket or folder, you must also include s3:PutObject and s3:GetObject.
>
> Warning: After you change these permissions, the user gets an Access
> Denied error when they access the main Amazon S3 console. The user
> must access the bucket using a direct console link to the bucket or
> folder.

Comment: Oh noooo. Say it isn't so. That's awful. :(

Comment: Well, at least I don't need to grant `DeleteObjectVersion`.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue and I found that only permissions needed to rename S3 object are:

```
"s3:GetObjectACL",
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:PutObjectACL"
```

`s3:DeleteObject` is not needed and it is quite dangerous especially in case if versioning is not enabled on the S3 bucket. I tested with both `s3:DeleteObject` and without it and it is still works.

Answer (score 1):

I think these permission will be helpful, I had tried it!

```
"Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mx-provider-video-upload/9a9036/*"
        ]
```

Comment: and then you don't need to worry WRITE_ACP of ACL permission

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to give access to a particular bucket for e.g. Sample and its objects.These permissions will serve your purpose.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1448568376000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to rename a file in AWS s3 I try and it doesn't take and says it failed